# NVIDIA prime-select on-demand never utilizes the GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, nvidia-prime

`nvidia-smi`:

```
Fri Jan 15 17:52:29 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   35C    P8     8W /  N/A |      9MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      4312      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8857      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This output never changes and I have not found a way to run any applications on the GPU.
In Gnome, although there is a an option to "Launch using dedicated graphics" it does not seem to actually launch the app with the GPU (KDE does not even seem to have such an option).

How can I make apps run on the GPU?

Shouldn't some apps automatically be run by the GPU in On-Demand mode?

Why is /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg the only process and only running with 4MB GPU Memory?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an on-demand prime profile?

If yes, then if you are on Steam (gaming) for example you have to insert a launch option like this:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia %command%
```

Comment: This should be accepted as solution