# Is it possible to run games on a headless NVIDIA Tesla GPU without the use of VMs?

Tags: games, gpu, nvidia-optimus, gpu-driver, nvidia-prime

I own an NVIDIA Tesla K20m GPU, which has no video outputs, and have actually been able to game with it through the use of Windows 10 virtual machines. However, I'm curious to know if it's possible to run games on this device bare metal.

For this, I must also say that the computer which the K20 is running on has a second GPU: a very old AMD ATI FirePro V4800 that exists to supply necessary video output. I don't actually use it to output the games of the K20 in the VM; instead I stream its output with services like Parsec or Sunshine.

But, if I were to install Ubuntu Desktop on this device, could I configure it to render games on the Telsa K20 and output video through the FirePro? I've tried it in the past (by using an x.org conf file to set my Tesla as the primary GPU) and was actually able to get one program working (Heaven Benchmark), but every other game I tried failed to start properly. If this setup is possible, would someone be willing to walk me through it? Do I need to insert a launch option like described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317282/1584710)?

Thanks!